# True Polymorph: can a player use legendary actions of its new form?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

### *True Polymorph*

PHB 283:

> **Creature into Creature.** (...) the new form can be any kind you choose. The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, **are
> replaced by the statistics of its new form.** It retains its alignment and personality. (...)
>
> The creature is limited in the actions it can perform by the nature of its new form (...).

### **Example**

Let's say a high level player (wizard, bard, etc) casts *True Polymorph* to change an ally into another creature with legendary actions (such as a dragon, a mummy lord, a vampire, etc). Would this ally's form change into the complete stat block (excluding alignment and personality) of the new form? Would the ally thus be **able to use the new form's Legendary Actions?** If not, which rule would prevent that?

### Confusion

According to MM 6 **"stat block"** of a creature **means the same as** its **"game statistics"**. This suggests that the answer to my question is a yes. However, Legendary Actions are not mentioned in the section listing what's part of the stat block (MM 6-11), under header *Statistics.* They are *only* mentioned under header *Legendary Creatures*. Is there a reason for this?

My common sense tells me that I should ignore this typographic detail. Just making sure there's no rules preventing players from getting Legendary Actions.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## No

The rule on this was changed in the [Monster Manual errata](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/MM-Errata.pdf) (and recent printings):

> If a creature assumes the form of a legendary creature, such as through a
>   spell, it doesn’t gain that form’s legendary actions, lair actions,
>   or regional effects.

Comment: You would think that could have been added as well to the PHB errata for the spell...

Comment: @Slagmoth Yeah, even in the recent books it appears in a weird space (not everyone reads the introduction). I guess it is easier to put it here in case they make new spells in the future that let you change your form.

Comment: Agreed, the introduction in most of the books isn't really that interesting or important but for the Monster Manuals it has been crucial for a good many years. So some advice to all you new players and DMs, READ IT.

Comment: @Slagmoth: XGE has a pretty vital one too.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I did say "most" :) but yeah forgot about that one, "Ten things to remember" is vital rules clarification and really the only thing in that book that is not really optional.

Comment: What about legendary resistances? They are not mentioned here